# How do I run multiple wildcard java files on multiple lines with javac properly?

Tags: command-line-interface, javac

I am trying to run javac on multiple wildcarded directories set up like below:

```
javac src/main/java/game/*.java
src/main/java/tile/*.java
src/main/java/player/*.java
src/main/java/gui/*.java
```

When I paste in the command in a linux docker command line, all I get is each line executed one at a time.  It compiles for the first command but it seems to forget that java exists for every line after as seen below for example:

[image]

## Attempt 2

I then tried to `\` every new line, but this resulted in concatenating the lines into one giant text stream inside the javac command, the result of which is seen below:

[image]

## Attempt 3

Finally, I just spaced each one out next to each other using the `-classpath` option, and it could not find the first directory in that case as seen below:

[image]

## Question

How do I simply run `javac` with multiple lines of wildcarded java files like I am attempting to do above?

Comment: Try " \" with a space?

Comment: @rogerdpack Doing that then gave me "error: invalid flag: <directory>/*.java.

Comment: Try `echo ...` (echo at the beginning of the other commands) to see what command bash is seeing?  In my experience if bash says "x/y/*.java" it means no files are actually there...zsh actually complains when this is the case with a * ...

Comment: In your first attempt, it looks like there are line breaks present, so that there are four distinct lines of input – the first is "javac ...", the second is a line "src/main/java/tile/*.java", etc. If there are in fact line breaks, that's probably the issue. Each line is treated like a standalone command, which isn't what you want. To fix, remove the line breaks.